# iPhone simulator no longer displaying 4 inch display correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

When I set my emulator for 3.5 inch it works fine.  It use to work fine  when I changed it to 4 inch.  Now the emulater is the size of a 4 inch screen.  Inside is the screen set up for a 3.5 inch, where it has black top and bottom margin.  It looks like the 3.5 inch display is being drawn in the center of the 4 inch screen.

My back up still works, but I would loose a lot of code I added to it.

Comment: FYI - It's a simulator, not an emulator.

Comment: Is your 4 inch (-568) splash screen definitely included?

Comment: Yep its not Android xD, anyways are you using storyboard/Xibs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Default-568h@2x.png as your launch image to support 4 inch display.  You also need your code to adjust for the larger screen size.